# How to display image on web browser which returns from api response in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, image-processing, ionic2, ionic3

I want to display image on web browser, the image file returns from api response. if we want to display image in device then we can download it, store it in device memory and we can display it. but how can we display image in web browser? is there any way to download and store image in browser?

what i have tried is below...

```js
this.sProvider.getLogo(this.logoHeaders)
    .then(result => {
        console.log("getLogo " + JSON.stringify(result));

        this.img = result._body;
});
```

html

```html
<div>
     <img src="{{img}}" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[]` to bind `src` for `<img>` tag :

```html
<img [src]="img" />
```

Comment: `img` should be a path like following : `/assets/myfile.png` or `http://someApi/file.png` or any image extension

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
<img [src]="img" >
```

If it is not works kindly send What do you get result here?

```
this.img = result._body;
```

Comment: {"_body":"�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000�x��\u0000\u0000\u0000\tpHYs\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0013\u0000\u0000\u000b\u0013\u0001\u0000��\u0018\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0019tEXtSoftware\u0000Adobe ImageReadyq�e<\u0000\u0000+\u0000IDATx���\r��u}'��s_ro \t\t%�(/��- t��m`\b��\u0019�6e\u0017GdWJ��\u0002��!\b�\"o��Ԍ�0�.8�5\u0016���Zi�3ڕ8\u0006Gw��\u0010�.E\u0010\u0004K\u000bT^rs_���;�^��\u001b�/�s�����\u001cO\u0012̽7�s���>��[��j%\u0010Nz��׷�N�

Comment: convert the result into base64 format. then bind '<img [src]="img" >' as like this.

Comment: any other option  with out converting into base64?

Comment: as per the result it's looks like matrix format. If the matrix changed to base64 you can able to display by using this tag '<img [src]="img" >'. 
Or use '<img [attr.src]="img" >' it might be work which is not sure.

Comment: @RajkumarGanesan consider using comments instead of answers if you need to get more clarification from the original poster of a question.  Think about this from the perspective of a Googler.  If someone had the same problem as the original poster, would your answer help them out?  Note that the answer could be improved if you included a full set of steps the original poster could use to debug the issue given your snippets.